# dynamic tag count on keyup

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that contains many spans and each of those spans contains a single href.

Basically it's a tag cloud. I have a textbox with a keyup event that filters the tag cloud div (It actually just hides the tags if not in filter condition).

Is there a way to get a count of the tags shown as the keyup event occurs?

Thanks,
rodchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("#filter_input").keyup( function() {
    count = $("#cloud span:visible").size();
    // Do something with the counted spans.
});
```

That should do it, substitute values as needed.

Comment: you was a little bit faster ;-)

Comment: And doesn't require a class on the a tag, too =o

Answer (score 2):

jquery size() Returns the number of matched elements.

$('.tags span a.visible').size();